# what is the solution of error message when launching PARAVIEW?

Tags: paraview

I've installed Paraview in my laptop.

When I try to launch it, it shows me an error message telling me that `GLEW could not be initialized, and the versionsfunction are not supported  on OPENGL ES`

How to fix it?

```
ERROR: In C:\bbd\7cc78367\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 819
vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow (000000000937A9A0): GLEW could not be initialized.


ERROR: In C:\bbd\7cc78367\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkShaderProgram.cxx, line 409
vtkShaderProgram (00000000099A1F90): 

Generic Warning: In C:\bbd\7cc78367\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkOpenGLRenderTimer.cxx, line 104
vtkOpenGLRenderTimer::Stop called before vtkOpenGLRenderTimer::Start. Ignoring.

versionFunctions: Not supported on OpenGL ES
```

Comment: Is that the complete error message text? If not can you paste that into your question?

Comment: please specify: OS, GPU, graphic driver.